# How to hide a specific div element when we reduce the zoom size of a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to hide a specific div element when we reduce the zoom size of a browser.Any help will be appreciated .Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried chief

Comment: @basic I have tried  through jquery but output not matched as my requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS for that with media query like

`@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .class-to-hide{ 
     display: none
   }
}`

Or if u wants to use jQuery just locate your class with $ or

`document.getElementById('myClass').css("display","none")`, use `$(window).height()` to get size of view port and create 'if' condition where you can put your hiding code.

Answer (score -1):

Try JS approach

```js
window.onresize = function(event) {
  let d=document.querySelector(".val");
  let zoom = window.devicePixelRatio * 100;
  
  zoom<=80 ? d.classList.add('hide') : d.classList.remove('hide');
  
  d.innerText=zoom;
};
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="val">Decrease zoom below 80%<div>
```

or pure CSS approach

```css
@media (max-resolution: 80dpi) {
  .val {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="val">Decrease zoom below 80%</div>
```